# Retrieving a row when specific text strings occur in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, hive, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to retrieve rows that contain only a specific text string(s). The issue is that sometimes the text string can me mixed in with other text strings, and when this occurs, I do NOT want to retrieve this row. Here's an idea of the data that I'm working with:

```
    MED_TABLE
______________________________________
med_code    |   med_name
______________________________________
1            calcium potassium iodine fluoride
2            potassium calcium
3            hydrochloride; calcium
4            iodine, calcium, fluoride
5            iodine calcium phosphate
6            calcium phosphate 
7            IODINE
8            calcium PHOSPHATE iodine
```

If I want to return rows that ONLY contain the strings 'calcium phosphate' and/or 'iodine', either independently or in pair, what's an efficient way of going about this? In this case, I would only want to return rows 5, 6, 7, 8.

I was trying to do this by using a query like this:

```
SELECT med_code, med_name
FROM med_table
WHERE lower(med_name) LIKE '%calcium phosphate%'
OR WHERE lower(med_name) LIKE '%iodine%'
```

But this returns rows that contain text strings that I do not want.

Comment: please tag with the database platform

Answer (score 0):

You must replace both terms and commas with empty strings, then trim the result and check if the length is 0:

```
SELECT med_code, med_name
FROM med_table
WHERE
  length(trim(
    regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(lower(med_name), 'calcium phosphate', ''), 'iodine', ''), ',', '')
  )) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4DBFfGUvjM5uhgSc1Cjixk/1) (for MySql the difference is the use of `replace` instead of Hive's `regexp_replace`).
Results:

```
| med_code | med_name                 |
| -------- | ------------------------ |
| 5        | iodine calcium phosphate |
| 6        | calcium phosphate        |
| 7        | IODINE                   |
| 8        | calcium PHOSPHATE iodine |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the text with like and then just compare the length of the column this will give the above result which you are expecting

```
SELECT med_code, med_name
FROM med_table
WHERE (lower(med_name) LIKE '%calcium phosphate%' AND length(Column)=18 

OR WHERE (lower(med_name) LIKE '%iodine%' AND length(Column)= 7)
```

The length of the column should be the Length of the string of LIKE clause check the syntax as just wrote this runtime Also add the condition for both combination of string like 'calcium phosphate iodine' and 'iodine ....'

Answer (score 0):

Use `rlike`:

```
with your_data as (
select stack (8,
1,'calcium potassium iodine fluoride',
2,'potassium calcium',
3,'hydrochloride\\; calcium',
4,'iodine, calcium, fluoride',
5,'iodine calcium phosphate',
6,'calcium phosphate' ,
7,'IODINE',
8,'calcium PHOSPHATE iodine') as (med_code,med_name)
)

select * from your_data 
 where med_name rlike '(?i)calcium phosphate' --(?i) means case insensitive
    or med_name rlike '^(?i)iodine$'          --with string begin(`^`) and end(`$`) anchors
;
```

Returns:

```
your_data.med_code  your_data.med_name  
5   iodine calcium phosphate    
6   calcium phosphate   
7   IODINE  
8   calcium PHOSPHATE iodine
```

This works in Hive